# W3 slideshow implementation doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, slideshow

https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_slideshow_fading

Using the link above, you can see an example of an animated fading slideshow that I am trying to implement into my website. However, when I copy the exact code and use it for me, it displays the images stacked on top of one another as one image, and just fades it in and out to the same image (made up of all of the images).

Any idea why this is happening or another source where I can get an animated slideshow from? The only other thing to take into account is that in the styles file, everything referring to 'webkit' is underlined in red. I am running in chrome though so I don't think that is the issue.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<body>

<div class="w3-content w3-section" style="max-width:500px">
  <p>The w3-animate-fading class animates an element in and out (takes about 10 seconds).</p>

  <img class="mySlides w3-animate-fading" src="../../assets/img/img_rr_01.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="image1">
  <img class="mySlides w3-animate-fading" src="../../assets/img/img_rr_02.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="image2">
  <img class="mySlides w3-animate-fading" src="../../assets/img/img_rr_03.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="image3">
  <img class="mySlides w3-animate-fading" src="../../assets/img/img_rr_04.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="image4">
</div>

<script>
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
    x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    setTimeout(carousel, 9000);    
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is exactly the code on the website, and I downloaded the images they use, so why is it that I can't get it to work?

Comment: Please share your code with us here as a StackSnippet (`[<>]`)

Comment: Just added the code @Luca

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<body>

<div class="w3-content w3-section" style="max-width:500px">
  <p>The w3-animate-fading class animates an element in and out (takes about 10 seconds).</p>

  <img class="mySlides w3-animate-fading" src="img_rr_01.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="image1">
  <img class="mySlides w3-animate-fading" src="img_rr_02.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="image2">
  <img class="mySlides w3-animate-fading" src="img_rr_03.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="image3">
  <img class="mySlides w3-animate-fading" src="img_rr_04.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="image4">
</div>

<script>
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
    x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    setTimeout(carousel, 9000);    
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here its working correctly. It may me something else that would be causing some problem.

Comment: Any ideas of what could cause it not to work the same way? Because I literally just copy and pasted your code and it still doesn't work the same...

Comment: check whether JavaScript is enabled in your browser or not, also try other browser to test.

Comment: JavaScript is enabled in my browser, and testing with firefox and with internet explorer resulted in a blank page completely

Comment: try running it in chrome and inspect your webpage and go to console menu, check are there any Js related error there?

Comment: no, there is only one statement and I think it is always there: Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.

Comment: It seems like the issue is that setting the style.display = "none" and to "block" within the function is just being ineffective. No I haven't, but I can give that a try now, I just will end up having to move it into the project though

Comment: It works in a different project, so I guess it is something in my project that is messing with it